# convey OSM file data into an obstacle space for path planning purposes

Tags: python, openstreetmap

in order to finish a project, I need to extract data from a private OSM file of an underground garage in XML format into a obstacle list with cartesian coordinates in python.

In the osm file, there are several nodes with long/lat are given which I want to store in a X/Y list in python.

I already thought about extracting the data with pandas from an excel file, but maybe there is an easier way or library which I dont know yet.

Thanks in advance.